# C++ Truncation of constant value

Tags: c++, hex

I'm getting this warning

```
warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
```

and when I try to execute my dll it only sends 4 bytes instead of the 10 bytes.
What could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{

    cout << "[SEND:" << len << "] ";

    for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        printf( "%02x ", static_cast<unsigned char>( buf[i] ) );
    }

    printf("\n");

    //causing the warning:
    char storagepkt[] = {0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x40, 0x79, 0xEA, 0x60, 0x1D, 0x6B, 0x3E};

    buf = storagepkt;
    len = sizeof(storagepkt);

    return pSend(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
int (WINAPI *pSend)(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags) = send;
int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);
```

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested I tried memcpy:

```
memcpy((char*) buf, storagepkt, sizeof(storagepkt));
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
unsigned char storagepkt[] = {0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x40, 0x79, 0xEA, 0x60, 0x1D, 0x6B, 0x3E};
```

Fixed it.

Comment: The code calls `pSend()`, but that isn't presented.  Instead is `MySend()`.  Is there a typo, or something missing?

Comment: I'm using detours. both are declared :)

Comment: @wallyk `pSend` is being called from inside `MySend`

Comment: @JanDvorak:  Looks like an indentation problem.  I'll fix it.

Comment: What line is causing the warning message? Are you sure that pSend() actually works?

Comment: char storagepkt, is causing the warning.

Comment: `buf` is a pointer. `buf = storagepkt` will overwrite the function argument. Perhaps you wanted to copy the _contents_ of `storagepkt` to `buf`? If so, look for [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: What does printing `len` show?

Comment: The array literal seems correct to me.

Comment: I think it's just complaining that you're intializing a char array with ints, but since they all fit in an 8-bit (unsigned) integer, you can probably ignore the warning

Comment: printing len gives the size of ten. But its not sending the storagepkt.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're initializing a buffer of `char` which is signed. Anything over `0x7f` is beyond what it can handle and will be converted to a negative number. The actual data is probably OK and you can ignore the warning, although it would be better to make it `unsigned char`.

As for why it's only sending 4 bytes, that sounds suspiciously like the size of a pointer. Are you sure the code is exactly as you've represented it, using an array, rather than a pointer passed to a function? A function doesn't know the size of an array even when you declare the parameter as an array - you need to pass the size of the array into the function.

Comment: 0xEA (storagepkt[5]) is too big for a char on compilers that consider char signed.

Answer (score 6):

I can reproduce this warning with the following code:

```
char aa = 0xff;
```

the warning is solved with

```
unsigned char aa = 0xff;
```

(as Mark Ransom already pointed out, I just added a minimal sample code to reproduce the warning)

Answer (score 0):

I also can reproduce this warning with following code:

```
const unsigned short cid = 0xdeadfeeb;
```

Which means that value is being truncated by compiler, because it is out of `unsigned short` range. Decrease value to solve warning.